# DC Motor Problem Explanation

Tags: dc, dc-motor

Can someone explain to me how we got the values for Id and Ud, also how we got that speed and current in armature?

The reference for this problem is our professor's chalkboard. I copied it in my paper and rewrote it here after translating it from Arabic to English.

> A perfectly compensated separately excited DC motor has the following nominal characteristics:
>
> Voltage: U = 220 V
> Current: I = 20 A
> Excitation current: iex = 1.5 A
> Armature resistance: R = 1 Ω
> Speed: N = 1200 rpm
>
> This motor operates on a load whose resisting torque varies as a function of the rotational speed. The torque characteristic Cr=f(N) of this machine is approximated by a straight line passing through the points:
>
> (N(rpm), Cr(Nm)): (0, 10), (2000, 50)
>
> The proportionality ratio K (Vs/rd) between the emf E and the rotational speed N is k = 5/pi V.s/rad
>
> The mechanical torque characteristic has the equation:  = 5/ ( − /6 ).
>
> Cr=0.02N+10.
>
> 2. To adjust the speed of the "motor+load" assembly, the armature supply voltage is adjusted while keeping iex=1.5A constant.
>
> The group starts without a rheostat: Calculate the minimum voltage to be applied and the armature current at the moment of start-up.
> Answer: Id=6.28A, Ud=6.28V
>
> From the characteristics Cr(N) and C(N), establish the relationship N=f(U).
>
> Calculate the speed and current in the armature for U=100V and U=220V.
>
> Answer: (N=525 rpm, I=12.5A), (N=1197 rpm, I=20.5A)

Comment: So what did the professor do?   Show us what you do know.  Edit your question with an attempt at an answer.  We are not a homework service.